# How can I draw on a surface using the grease pencil without zoom offset inconsistencies in Blender 2.8?

Tags: grease-pencil

Drawing over a mesh with the grease pencil using the Surface option and an offset has issues depending upon whether I zoom in/out at any point.

Has anyone else experienced this? If so, do you have any workaround? The only option I've found is to never adjust the zoom of the viewport while drawing.

I posted this as a bug but the response was focused more on the offset not matching the geometry. The solution provided was to duplicate and scale a mesh to the desired offset. The problem is, the offset is **always different** because of the viewport zoom distance so the strokes on a scaled mesh don't match.

Comment: Yes! As a test I dropped in a sphere and drew some lines w/ 0.00001 offset, zoomed out and drew crossing lines. Rotate the view and the second set of lines is significantly further away from the sphere. What I really want is "draw as close as possible w/o clipping", but the current offset is unusable.

Comment: I posted this as a bug but the response is that it's a limitation of code and drawing performance, so I think we're stuck with it for now. I don't have a full solution but converting the GP paths to Bezier and then shrinkwrapping those gets close. It's just a silly, baked in approach.

Comment: If they added a shrinkwrap modifier to GP that would probably be a better solution anyway! Maybe you could mention it in your issue?

Comment: This is a good work around solution. She clearly and easily explains her process https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YY0gjIttZRw

Answer (score 2):

The only official mention of this issue that I could find is a bug report from 2019: https://developer.blender.org/T61854

Here the issue is demonstrated very well.

The developers at the time believed that the proper solution would be a shrinkwrap modifier for grease pencil.

There are feature requests for this [here](https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/WTbbbc/) and [here](https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/9zcbbc/) that you can upvote for visibility.

For now - to draw on mesh surface there is a bit of a hacky workaround thanks to Sophie Jantak: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YY0gjIttZRw&t=252s

Essentially it is this:

- Give mesh a solidify modifier with an offset of 1, hide modifier in render view
- Draw with placement set to Surface & offset to 0

Now the stroke will be placed uniformly against the mesh regardless of zoom level, the only real issue being that while working the strokes are still slightly clipped by the mesh - you can toggle the modifier in viewport on/off to see it more clearly if needed.

Hopefully we will see a nicer official solution soon.